# Scrape data with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this url - https://www.vndirect.com.vn/portal/thong-ke-thi-truong-chung-khoan/lich-su-gia.shtml - and I want to **scrape** data from it using Python (with BeautifulSoup or something).

Here is an example of the data I want to scrape:

[image: Table of data from vndirect.com.vn]

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: welcome to `Stack Overflow!` community, please [edit] your question and show you what you have tried with and where you failed ! check [ask] and provide [mcve]. be informed that the community is not offering code writing service or even handover your work assigments

Answer (score 0):

Use beautifulsoup to extract data and Pandas to store data in Data Frame.
iterate over values scraped through website.

Comment: That what I need, but could you more specific please?

Comment: @FlyAway look for a starter code which fetches data (bs4) then try to change it to cater your needs. once that's achieved understand how dataframe works, then use it as a data structure to hold data. if you get stuck meanwhile, post a code you have been trying run and your exact output required.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use **Selenium**, you can use get data with each input. You need to try to build a program by yourself. The keyword is **Selenium**.